# Codekit 2 doesn't resolve Bonjour Hostname after Yosemite 10.10 Upgrade

Tags: bonjour, osx-yosemite, codekit

After upgrading to Yosemite 10.10 via the AppStore (no new/clean install), I get a blank page when previewing a website with Codekit 2. In the "Server" tab the Bonjour Hostname in my case "lukas.local" is missing since the upgrade http://goo.gl/QduPqp.

Any ideas how to expose my Bonjour hostname correctly again? Thanks!

Comment: I'm also having this issue... since the Yosemite update. Do you get a 403 Forbidden if you navigate to just [http://localhost/](http://localhost/)?

Comment: No, my MAMP stack (Version 3.0.7.1) is working fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check your HostName - I had the same issue;

```
sudo scutil --get HostName
```

If you don't get back an expected result (ie. lukas.local) change it... along with the ComputerName and LocalHostName if they need changing...

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName Lukas
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName lukas
sudo scutil --set HostName lukas.local
```

Restart the CodeKit servers.

Hope that helps someone at least.

Comment: Ugh, glory hallelujah. This resolved all of my post-yosemite mDNS hair-pulling.  Is apple going to kill bonjour? (those bastards   )

Comment: I'm having same issue but my hostName seems to show in the preview tab of CodeKit. However Terminal says a hostName has not been set. Should I still give the about command a go? @Lukas

Comment: @samsos yeah just try to execute the three commans above, if `sudo scutil --get HostName` doesn't return anything - you can also try to assign it via System Preferences > Sharing

Comment: Bryan here (CodeKit developer). Just want to clarify that this issue is a problem in Yosemite and not CodeKit. Apple re-wrote the entire OS X networking stack to get rid of mDNSResponder. That re-write has been a headache for thousands and thousands of people, not just CodeKit users. I really wish there were something I could do or add to my app to work around Apple's shoddy development, but I'm afraid we just have to wait for them to fix the issues. Hopefully 10.10.3 will be better!

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me, but [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389) did:

Go to *Macintosh HD* > *Library* > *Preferences* > *SystemConfiguration* and delete the following files:

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
preferences.plist
```

**Then reboot the Mac.**

The host names should be recreated correctly.

(According to [this page](http://forums.imore.com/os-x-yosemite-10-10/304804-my-computer-name-changing-10-10-a.html) these are instructions provided by an Apple tech.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related blog post that discusses how your Bonjour network gets "poisoned" and how you can prevent it: http://furbo.org/2015/05/05/discoveryd-clusterfuck/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my  Yosemite 10.10 MBA and iMac, both on CodeKit 2.1.8. I managed to get it working on my MB by playing with the Computer Name in Preferences > Sharing > Computer Name, [making sure Internet Sharing is Off](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#troubleshooting), then restarting CodeKit.

However this doesn't work on my iMac.

Comment: No didn't work. When I restart Codekit then i get often a 'Unavailable' http://goo.gl/ERKwrM

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour is broken on all upgraded Mac Book Pro on WiFi so :

- unable to make CodeKit work
- same thing to print on my network printers
- unable to mount a local server
- to make a ping niania.local work, you need first to ping the ip address of the computer, then the local name will work (stupid of course)
- etc...

Just plug an Ethernet cable and it will perfectly work.

Always the same advice for major Mac OS X updates : wait for version 10.X.2 before upgrading.

Comment: Before connecting via cable, I have executed this command : `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist` to launch the bonjour daemon. Try it if not already done...

Comment: Nope again no luck… https://www.dropbox.com/s/nl2ei0qj59xx97n/Screenshot%202014-10-30%2013.51.23.png?dl=0 Maybe a fresh clean install of OSX is the best solution :-)

Comment: Ok, I have found a workaround! My MacBookPro is connected to my 5Ghz airport network and Bonjour is not populated in Safari for example. As soon as I connect to my 2.4GHz network, all Bonjour features are immediately up and CodeKit works! I have tried to reinstall Yosemite from scratch without any backup, the problem persists so this is not an upgrade problem but a problem in Yosemite. yeah!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my macbook air with a new copy of Yosemite. To fix it, I changed the computer name in Sharing under system preferences

- Launch System Preferences
- select Sharing
- Unlock access from the bottom left if you need to, then edit the Computer Name to reflect what codekit launches when you hit preview.

Hope that works for you. setting the hostname via scutil didn't work for me